# Alternative to Google App Engine API?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm looking for an alternative of the Google App Engine API. I mean I'm searching an API for coding in JAVA that provides :

- Simple DB API, with no conf
- Simple User API, with no need to implements the login/register/user management process
- Simple Task API, with no need to configure any third lib

Google App Engine is really attractive because it provides all theses functionalities with no effort ... But I need to port my app to my own server... Using appScale is not for me because I don't need something really scalable ... I just want to code the business model, not all things that should already exists.

Hope my question is clear :)

Thanks in advance for help, sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run AppScale on a single node deployment, you'll just lack fault tolerance. I am currently unaware of any other project that runs Java GAE apps.